# How to select two set from collection in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection defined by:

```
public class CompanyModel
{
    public int compnSN { get; set; }
    public string compnName { get; set; }
    public string compnAddress { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get out two set `compnName` and `compnAddress` together so that I can use each of that pair value one by one in a `foreach` loop ?
I tried:

```
var pairs = from companies 
            select new {name = companies.compnName, addr = companies.compnAddress}
foreach (var item in pairs)
{
    //do some things with item.name;
    //do some things with item.addr;
}
```

I know this idea can be executed but is my grammar wrong somewhere?

Comment: Your code works for me.  What error are you getting?

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz if you correct the (wrong) code in the question, we don't understand what's going wrong... I rolled back.

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz I agree 100%, also someone downvoted me for this reason. Since the code wasn't thas is now posted.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus thank you for bringing back the original code !

Comment: var pairs = from company in companies select new {name = company.compnName, addr = company.compnAddress};

Comment: @KevinRoche: Somebody has already posted an answer with that in it.

Comment: @Christos: I see how this has all played out now. Apologies for inconvenience. P.S. I didn't downvote, I've been offline all afternoon.

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz no problem at all dude. Have a good night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var result = companies.Select(x => new 
                                   { 
                                       Name = x.compnName, 
                                       Address = x.compnAddress 
                                   });
```

or this one:

```
var result = from company in companies
             select new 
             {
                  Name = x.compnName, 
                  Address = x.compnAddress 
             };
```

Then as you already pointed out:

```
foreach(var company in result)
{
    // access the name like company.Name and do what you want.
    // access the address like company.Address and do what you want.
}
```

**UPDATE**

The code you have posted has some grammatical errors. So despite the fact that your logic is correct, this piece of code will not be compiled.

Specifically, in the following piece of code:

```
var pairs = from companies 
            select new {name = companies.compnName, addr = companies.compnAddress}
```

you try to declare a local variable called companies that should belong in a collection. 
Hence we should write this like below:

```
var pairs = from item in items
```

Now `item` is a local variable that refers to the random element in the collections called `items`. Then as you already have writen you will declare an anonymous type in the select clause:

```
var pairs = from item in items
            select new
            {
                PropertyA = item.PropertyA
                PropertyB = item.PropertyB
            };
```

Comment: Why not your first answer ? I am trying it...

Comment: @user1314404 I am sorry but I didn't get you. What you mean?

Comment: I mean your first answer before you editing it looks ok, Im trying it and it works well... just wonder why you edit it...

Comment: @user1314404 ah ok ! I just wanted to provide you with two solutions. I am glad that I helped.

Comment: You should explain what you've changed from the code in the question, as it appears to be primarily just whitespace/naming convention changes.

Comment: @Servy if I am right, the code var pairs = from  companies select new {name = companies.compnName, addr = companies.compnAddress} isn't correct. Hence, this code will not compile. On the other hand the code in my answer is close to the OP code but it's correct and does what original post want. If I am wrong, please let me know. thanks

Comment: @Christos You should not just post a code dump of altered code, particularly when the changes are subtle and hard to notice.  You should explain, in words, what was wrong with the code in the question, and what you changed to make it work.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, as I built and debug my code quite long. And now it run fine with your help. Kudo to your answer! THank you.

Comment: @user1314404 no problem dude ! I am glad that I could help.